# GPU driver not loaded when secure boot is enabled

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, secure-boot, 22.10

I had installed Ubuntu 22.04 (with secure boot on), but I upgraded to 22.10 with secure boot off. I went to enable secure boot, but the GPU driver (nvidia proprietary) wasn't loaded. Do I need some other drivers when I have secure boot on? What is the procedure?

Comment: Are you also running Windows 11? If not secure boot should be off.

Comment: I used to. I formatted when I installed Ubuntu, but left it on. Why it should be off? I know that Ubuntu doesn't require it, but why explicitly off?

Comment: To use linux with an nvidia driver and secure boot mode on, the nvidia driver has to be signed.   You can trigger the signing process by turning on secure boot, booting into linux, then dpkg-reconfigure the driver.  It should prompt for a one shot password that you need to give the MOK enroller next time you boot.  If you miss the MOK prompt, you can try again, or try to manually enroll it.

Comment: So you can load the GPU driver.

Comment: It's a s simple as this: Unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 for which Secure Boot is a requirement, you can just disable it. When not a requirement it's more of an annoyance than an actual useful feature.

Comment: Secure boot works with linux.   There are only two reasons to turn it off:  1) You have compiled a custom kernel and don't want to sign it, 2) you can't figure out how to get automatic driver signing working 3) you don't mind viruses being written into your EFI boot sequence

Comment: Did you try other versions of the driver?
525 (proprietary, tested) didn't work for me. But 515 did. And I still have secure boot enabled.

Answer (score 0):

My steps to make it work with secure boot were as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I pressed then a menu labeled as "Perform MOK Management" appeared, there were the following four options:

1 . Continue boot
2 . Enroll Key
3 . Enroll Key from Disk
4 . EnrollKey from Hash

I chose option number 2, then I continued to boot, it finally worked, I went to Ubuntu settings->Details and my Graphic Card name was shown correctly.

Comment: This worked because there was an update available that affected the driver.  Without the update, you could also force this with `dpkg --reconfigure` with the driver package.

Comment: Either you can simply add a password, in which case Ubuntu will use that password to sign kernel drivers, OR you can access your BIOS and turn off secure boot, which will turn off this message.