# Ubuntu not booting with Nvidia 4090

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I cannot boot to Kubuntu Linux on USB, (or from disk) with my new installed Nvidia 4090 video card. Possibly related I am seeing weird boot-menu behavior?

Tried booting with a new USB bootable drive with Kubuntu 23.04. (Also tried loading from disk, but just loads blank screen, powered left on.)

Trying to boot from USB: From the BIOS boot-menu, I have tried several options. 1st I select the USB: UEFI, then my monitor display goes blank (but stays powered on). I am not prompted to "Try Kubuntu" or "Install Kubuntu". I am not able to edit the kernel mode settings.

NOTE: I notice that one of my hard drives does not appear in the boot-menu options, except for a single time it randomly was listed on a power-off/re-try.

***That single time it appeared***, I selected USB: UEFI and I got some boot-up graphics. While trying to boot, I was prompted to enter my password the encrypted hard-drives. It flashed the Kubuntu logo, then went back to console text. It displayed this message:

```
nouveau 000:0a:00.0: unknown chipset (192000a1)
hid-generic 003:0D8C:0134.001: No inputs registered, leaving
```

It did nothing for a long time, and eventually I hit CTRL+ALT+DEL, which it responded to and reboot. After this single time, nothing else has worked. I am completely loss, please help?

System Info:

```
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 62.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor / Video Card: MSI RTX 4090 GAMING TRIO 24G
Motherboard Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: X570 AORUS ELITE WIFI
```

UPDATE: There were 2 problems. (1) One of the SATA connected hard-drives was not happy and I swapped it with another SATA drive's connection, and then it began to boot. (2) The GRUB boot Kernel options needed to be adjusted for Nvidia with 'nomodeset' being added.

Comment: Nouveau is the generic driver for older nVidia cards. Often does not work or work well with very new nVidia. Can you boot USB with Safe boot option. And if install, can you boot recovery mode. They use nomodeset to get default low quality graphics so you can install driver. Or terminal mode to manually install driver with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.  IF UEFI Secure boot on, you have to enroll a MOK - machine owner key. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438024/gpu-driver-not-loaded-when-secure-boot-is-enabled